How can I smooth the output of a DC motor used as a generator?
I have a small DC motor acting as a generator, spinning at 500RPM. From it, I get 1V with ½V ripple, which a 1000uF electrolytic capacitor smooths nicely.
I may wish to drive the motor in reverse, getting -1V.
To do smoothing in either situation I'd need a 1000uF unpolarised capacitor, which as far as I know you can't get.
Is there another way?

Is rectifying the output current an option?

you could use the non-polarised connection of two 2000uF in antiseries

1000 uF non-polarized capacitors DO exist, just Google it.  They may be pricey, but they are available.  @Neil_UK's suggestion will also work, as would rectifying output (though with only 1 V to work with that might not be desirable.)

Thanks. I will look for unpolarised caps.  Also, I'll try +-  -+ electrolytics - will that definitely be ok? Won't one of them always be under reverse polarity?  I won't do rectification, though - I want the positive and negative!

The +--+ electrolytics, shunt each capacitor with a schottky diode. That will limit the reverse voltage across each to -0.3 V, probably safe. They will rectify the AC to bias the centre terminal. If you have a bias supply available, or a small battery to hand, bias the middle terminal through a high value resistor to guarantee that each cap only sees the correct polarity.
